# PDF Generation with High Resultion SVG Images (suggestions needed!)

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, svg

Can anyone suggest/recommend a product that can be used to dynamically produce PDFs that can contain high-res images?

We're currently using a product called Highwire from a company called Corda to produce PDFs of our HTML pages.

Highwire is crap at producing PDFs though becuase it does not conform to HTML standards (i.e. it requires table layouts rather than CSS/Div layouts). We have to use it though because it is capable of incorporating high-definition SVG images into its PDF output.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: You want to create a PDF from existing HTML? Or programatically?

Comment: What the heck are 'high definition SVG images'? SVG are vector graphics. They have no definition as per definition.

Comment: Ok, by 'high definition' I am referring to the customer's wording. They want vector based graphics that when you zoom in, maintain their sharpness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [Prince](http://princexml.com/overview/)?

It can handle XHTML and CSS just fine as well as SVG.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop) together with [this stylesheet from HTML to XSL-FO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/) with success in some projects. Embedding SVG ist straight forward, since FOP incorporates Batik, Apache's SVG library. You can copy SVG images 1:1 to the XSL-FO file.